# log4net configuration in .net standard 1.3 project

Tags: c#, log4net, .net-standard

I'm trying to migrate a c# project from .net framework v4.6 to .net standard.
The project has log4net v2.0.8 dependency.

I found this [SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48215889/4791963), which recommends to use .net standard 1.3 and gives reference to [this post](https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/) to get more detailed solution.

The problem occurs when configuring log4net with `XmlConfigurator.Configure` method, which requires `ILoggerRepository` as the first argument.

In the post `LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())` method used, but `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly) in .net standard 1.3.

[Official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_Configure_2.htm) is also broken, because `XmlConfigurator.Configure` method signature and it's example usage doesn't match.

So, how can I configure log4net in .net standard 1.3 project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your .NET Standard 1.3 class library project, provide an `Assembly` argument in the signature of the method taking care of the `Log4net` configuration, eg:

```
public static void Configure(Assembly assembly)
{
    ILoggerRepository repository = LogManager.GetRepository(assembly);
    XmlConfigurator.Configure(repository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

    // ...
}
```

Call this method from your actual application, being developed in either the full .NET Framework or .NET Core, passing in this `Assembly` argument via eg: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`.

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is supported in both the full .NET Framework and .NET Core.