# How to use log4net in dotnet core DLL and read log4net.config

Tags: c#, dll, log4net, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .netcore 3.1 DLL project where I want to use log4net to writing log. I have added log4net from NuGet manager whenever I try to load config, I have to put log repository and configuration file path. I can not find out how I can get log repository. Below my code where I tried to load config

```
 public class LoggerHelper
 {
    private static readonly log4net.ILog _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    static LoggerHelper()
    {
        LoadConfig();
    }

    private static void LoadConfig()
    {
        //To load logger config I need log repository, log config file path
        //I have log config file path but I do not have log repository
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500512/log4net-configuration-in-net-standard-1-3-project/53506953#53506953) also applies for `.NET Core`.

Comment: Have a look at [Configure Log4Net logging in DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769414/configure-log4net-logging-in-dll)